# Download all files instead of view them in browser .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a folder called "files" I have a .htaccess file in there which job is to determine if the file is going to be "downloaded" or just viewed (NOT EXECUTED (.txt, .php etc) But I want image files to be viewed, as they are... images! So they shouldn't be downloaded.

I tried with

```
Header set Content-Disposition attachment
Header set Content-Type application/octet-stream
```

But that give me an error

How do I set up this rules?

1. Download files.
2. Show images (if Images, of course, show .pdf documents etc).
3. View (DONT EXECUTE!) .php, .txt etc.

---

Is this a secure method, by the way?

Comment: "But that give me an error" — **What** error?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12641607/808732

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First set download code for all then add code for specific file like image and PDF

```
<Files *.*>
ForceType applicaton/octet-stream
</Files>
<Files *.jpeg>
ForceType image/jpeg
</Files>
<Files *.jpg>
ForceType image/jpeg
</Files>
<Files *.pdf>
ForceType application/pdf
</Files>
```

Comment: if you are setting correct action for correct file then this is secure. let say for an example if you allow to upload .htaccess file on this folder root then this will create big problem. if you add some restriction while uploading then this will work. What I suggest check for all possible loopholes and restrict that. that's it

Comment: Yeah, I see. That was my idea with <Files *.*>
ForceType applicaton/octet-stream
</Files> I specify all files to download, and then I do some sort of "whitelist" that let the files what they should do, like if its a jpg i show its like a img, and if a pdf it shows like pdf. Yeah what could I do about .htaccess, I could add the .htaccess info above in the httpd.config, and then set .htaccess to just show as plain text or something?

Comment: Not sure about that. Please test yourself, i will respond you later once I am done research. cheer!!

Comment: Ok, I've experienced a little. Marked as answer.