# How do I force the browser download all file types in a directory using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

How would I tell the browser to force download all file types in a directory instead of rendering them inside the browser?
I've tried this but it didn't work.

```
<Files *.*>
ForceType applicaton/octet-stream
</Files>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that is possible. But you can use a mod_rewrite to a .php file with the file name in the GET part of the URL. Then extract the file name and force a download through that. If you want some download code, just ask

Answer (score 4):

This would be better tasked with:

```
<Files *.*>
Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</Files>
```

I use this with a `FilesMatch` instead of `Files`. Below is an example with text-based files

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:doc|odf|pdf|rtf|txt)$">
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```